# Access system files and folders

Tags: vb.net

When I try to access the folder "System Volume Information" and other system files I get the error

> Access to the path 'H:\System Volume Information' is denied.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Why do you want that? Generally accessing those files is prohibited for purpose and dealing with NTFS security is not really easy.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing in the "System Volume Information" directory that you need to access.

Comment: Mr.SixHouse, do have solution to my problem or not?

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look at the Environment object.  You haven't really told us what you are trying to accomplish.

Try this on for size, seems the question may have been asked.  Shouldn't be too hard to translate to VB.net.

[Checking file/folder access permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456397/checking-file-folder-access-permission)

Oh and regarding the "I don't have permission" after checking the access you may do a quick google on impersonation.  There are several interesting reads.

Comment: actually, I am now building an antivirus program.. and as you know most of viruses hide in these folders and most of viruses change its property to file system ... so, if I want to find them I most gain authority to access them from my program... I hope you have answer?

Comment: @Rasool: You're building an antivirus program in VB.NET? That's going to be a challenge. How are you detecting the viruses? Have you added a manifest that solves the UAC problem?

Comment: Body I have already built my anti-virus program I have a database that contain a large of MD5 signatures for most known viruses.... but I have one problem and this problem is my post... I hope you have a solution for it?