# What are security issues in creating file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am writing log for my application at a path saying :-

> "C:\Folder1\Folder2\Myfile.txt" (Configurable)

if this file does not exist I am creating folder structure and file inside my code(If there is no C drive I pop up a message saying log directory doesnt exist).

In code review a colleague said that I should not create folder and files using code rather should ask the client to create the file and only perform write operation on this file.

He says there are security issues with this but not sure what, so I thought of posting it here.

Please help me deciding whether I should create file if not exist or ask the client to create on every installation.

What are the security implications with the first approach?

Comment: You tagged this as asp.net question. Is your application a web application which saves data to disk, or a desktop application?

Comment: @Nikola, its a web application

Comment: The easiest way would be asking your colleague for clarification. I can't see any security issues here, but maybe he does. Let him explain.

Comment: @Nvoigt, yeah thats the easiest I agree but hard part is he doesnt remember and says had happened in his earlier project. He is new and I don't want to eat his head out. if I dont find any security issue he learns something else i will :) , anyways thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

The write issues are that the user trying to create in the `C` root folder, may not have permissions to create it there. Never assume the user is an admin always.

Also this is the problem with windows' UAC which will be a problem.

Comment: Thank you for your response, this is a web application and is impersoanated to admin user so creating folder is no issues. Any security implications? I mean like external user getting access to this and causing harm.

Comment: @PranaliDesai the asp.net web application will run in `Anonymous` user mode. Possibility is, the `inetpub` may not have access to `write` to create folders/files.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there could be issues.  Your program will most likely run under the interative user account and therefore be subject to any UAC conditions imposed on it.

One approach, if this is just a log file, would be to use a temporary file, so use:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx

This should be created in a an area local to the logged on user that should allow writing of files.

Answer (score 0):

The security issue i see is the ability of your web application to access and write the files inside the directory (configurable, as you mentioned).

To verify the the access by checking the permissions given to the account under which your apppool is running

or through code [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456397/checking-file-folder-access-permission)

Comment: this is for log file and configurable value is stored in web.config, I don't see how a user of my webapplication can writes files. If it is the client doing intentionally all belongs to him he can screw up his resources I am not bothered :)

Comment: but your web app writes the log file, so the security account under which your web app is running should have sufficient rights to modify the file.

Comment: it impersonates admin so no worries about that

Answer (score 0):

No code is inherently unsafe. This all depends on how rest of your code looks like, but as a general rule of thumb you should limit which files your application can access and how it can access them. Limit this as much as possible, without damaging your applications functionality.

Security vulnerabilities which may come from this is allowing user to read file which he shouldn't read, or write to an important file and damage it that way. For example, if file path is being created using user input, user may modify the path so that he accesses file which is not allowed to access.
If you create a path like so:

```
string filePath = "c:\\mysafefolder\\" + fileName;
```

and user enters a relative path, for example `..\Windows\Passwords.txt` he will effectively gain access to `c:\windows\passwords.txt`.

If you configure your application to block access to any part of file system except `mysafefolder`, this attempt to read a secret file will fail.

This is just an example of what might happen, and why it is a good idea to limit your application permissions. Your code might be perfectly safe at this point, but limiting permissions is thinking ahead.