# File access differences between FileStream and System.IO.File method

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, file-io, filestream

In one of my projects I am using a path in the `System.Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData` folder (in my case C:\ProgramData) to store configuration and registration data. However I ran into problems. I check if I can access the files by using the routine

```
Dim isok As Boolean = True
Try
   Dim ftry As New IO.FileStream(frmMain.APPDATA & "\regid.bin", FileMode.Open)
   ftry.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
  isok = False
End Try
```

APPDATA is the path to my config folder and I check if the file actually exists before that as well (it does). On one machine this routine returns false for me. The exception says no file access.
If I rewrite this routine:

```
Dim isok As Boolean = True
Try
   Dim contents() as Byte = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(frmMain.APPDATA & "\regid.bin")
Catch ex As Exception
  isok = False
End Try
```

It returns true, so the IO routines obviously can access the file.

Can someone explain to me what the difference between the two methods are? Shouldn't file access be determined by the application's privileges? Is there a better way to determine if I have read/write access to the file?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend opening the file to determine access rights. See this Answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3456514/468973

Comment: As as aside, don't use string concatenation to create filenames.  Use the methods in the Path class, specifically, use `Path.Combine(frmMain.APPDATA, "regid.bin")`

Comment: You're correct Chris. In this case it doesn't really make a difference since I know what's inside APPDATA at any point. But you are right that the path.combine approach is a good idea in most cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `FileStream` constructor passes off to another constructor overload.. namely this one:

```
internal FileStream(string path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, int bufferSize, FileOptions options, string msgPath, bool bFromProxy, bool useLongPath, bool checkHost)
```

The `FileAccess` it passes by default is `FileAccess.ReadWrite`. If your application does not have write permissions.. chances are this will fail.

On the other hand, `File.ReadAllBytes` does this:

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(..., ..., FileAccess.Read, ...
//                                                      ^^^^ this
```

Notice `File.ReadAllBytes` uses the `FileAccess.Read` value.

So that's the difference. `FileStream.ctor` uses `FileAccess.ReadWrite`, `File.ReadAllBytes` uses `FileAccess.Read`.

TLDR: Your app needs write permissions to use that basic constructor for `FileStream`. Remember there is a `File.Exists` method that is meant for this exact purpose. Opening and closing a file to see if it exists is not the right way to go about it.

Comment: Thank you. I will check if I have write permissions to the file and report back.

Comment: Ok, I indeed only have read access to the file on that computer. This is pretty weird in itself and I don't know why but that explains the given scenario. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

use IO.File.Exist() routine to check if the file exist. You don't need to read the file content.

Comment: I do this as I wrote in my post. But only existance of the file is not enough and says nothing about the access permissions to the file.

Comment: use IO.File.GetAccessControl method and add a new security rule.