# 'System.IO.FileLoadException' with newtonsoft-json

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, dll, json.net

The debugger keeps giving me this 'System.IO.FileLoadException' error message in the output window of Visual Studio everytime I call the toJSONString() method in a dll assembly I had created earlier. See method below. I used NuGet to load and reference the newtonsoft-json.dll library, so why a runtime attempt keeps failing is beyond me.

```
Object output;
...
public String toJSONString()
{
    String strOut = "";
    if (output != null)
    {
        strOut = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(output);
    }

    return strOut;
}
```

In the Solutions Explorer window, under References, I checked the path for Newtonsoft.Json which is C:\temp2\DataTables_Examples\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll. That dll file does exist there. I don't know why the app doesn't see it? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to Clean and Rebuild the solution.

Comment: did you try `update-package Newtonsoft.Json -reinstall` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be an issue with your package versioning.
Try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22685530/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-newtonsoft-json-or-one-of-its-dependencies-ma) presented for someone with a similar error.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  That helped.  Found the solution.  My web.config file didn't have a reference to the newtonsoft.json package and my dll project was referencing a different version of the newtonsoft.json package.  Once both projects were referencing the same version, everything worked.  I don't understand why, however, they have to be the same version?

Answer (score 0):

Have you any software opened, that is viewing the library or a folder of it?
(like NotePad++ or whatever) Also it would be better, if you include the package directly in your project. Maybe you should try to find out, if the file exists for your studio(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx).
(example from the page)

```
string curFile = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
Console.WriteLine(File.Exists(curFile) ? "File exists." : "File does not exist.");
```

Maybe this link also helps, to check your (studio)acces rights:
[Checking file/folder access permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456397/checking-file-folder-access-permission)

Comment: The project does include the package directly.  The dll library I created earlier also has a copy of the same package that it references. I inserted the code you provided and it does return File exists.